# Aproximately optimal high k-quatization: lagrange multiplier constraint

Tags: signal-processing, means, mean-square-error

I'm observing the quantization topic in signal processing and there is some mathematical term,
which I'm not totally understand. Here is the start of the development of the quantization for k > 1 (a few slides with some pretty understandable mathematical equations development ), after I learned the quantization for k=1 (i.e the expectation):
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Provided one more slide for the context understanding, after the part I don't understand.

What is the reason for using in the marked slide Lagrange multipliers, what this constraint meant for to achieve ?
It is also defined that : $\sum \mu _i=M$, after which the Lagrange constraint is set to be: $\lambda \left(M-\sum \mu _i\right)$, isn't it 0, according to the definition ?
Here is a link to the whole lecture material:
[k-quatization](https://www.scribd.com/document/484020829/Lecture-2)

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal M-\sum \mu_i=0$. That is the constraint. It comes from (73).

Comment: I´m wondering where the sigma sign has gone from (75) to (76).

Comment: differentiating by only one $u_i$

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.